# Выбор обьекта

Tags: jquery

В общем ситуация такая: у меня есть 3 `div` с одним `id`. При клике на них они подсвечиваются, но выбрав сначала один `div` а затем второй, тогда в результате получим два подсвеченных дива. Как сделать, чтоб при клике на `div`, была проверка, на то, что до этого не выбран уже див?

Comment: а что мешает использовать class="class1 class2 class3" к примеру?

Comment: надо будет попробовать. просто задание получил не по специализации, вот разбираю его теперь

Answer (score 3):

Для начала: 3 дива с одним ID - это плохо. Очень плохо. Используйте классы.

Далее: допустим, подсвечивается он при помощи:

.addClass('active');

Тогда

```
$('#MyDiv').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    //Див на котором кликнули - подсвечен.
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }else{
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }

});
```

Старики меня убъют за такую проверку с айдишником. Но я не виноват, об этом я написал в первой строке.

Comment: разніе классы есть, но один айди тоже нужен.

Comment: не вижу ни единой причины острой необходимости одинаковых id разных элементов.
Все можно решить без этого.

Comment: а вас не смущает, что будет выбран только первый див с таким id?

Comment: нет, так как использую метод each()

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, а можно использовать метод `.toggleClass()`

```
$('#MyDiv').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Три дива, с одним классом (один id использовать нельзя, разные должны быть):
<div class="hilite"></div>
<div class="hilite"></div>
<div class="hilite"></div>
И скрипт:
<script>
$('.hilite').click(function(){
    $('.hilite').removeClass('active'); // снимаем со всех выделение
    $(this).addClass('active'); // выделяем кликнутый
});
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо! попробую такой вариант